# Create/fill form with values from uploaded CSV

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, csv

I've decided that to accomplish my task, I need to take the CSV file that is uploaded on my first page, and build a form from it filling the inputs with the CSV values.

I have a functioning CSV upload, but this is to view the CSV and make edits to the fields before saving. I have a while loop that I think I should build the form inside. The only trick is that I've built a CSV data array that handles it upon upload and it's 229 elements long. I need to build the form names to mirror it, so I"ll essentilally be naming 229 form fields, which is fine. Here is the current code that successfully  loads the CSV into a table when the button is clicked:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$maxPreviewRows = PHP_INT_MAX;  // this will be ~2 billion on 32-bit system, or ~9 quintillion on 64-bit system
$hasHeaderRow = true;

    echo '<table>';

    /*WE WILL NEED TO QA CONDITIONS AND HIGHLIGHT IN RED HERE. ALSO NEED BORDER STYLINGS*/

    if ($hasHeaderRow) {
        $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach($headerRow as $value) {
            echo "<th>$value</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr></thead>';
    }

    echo '<tbody>';

    $rowCount = 0;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';

}
```

So, that successfully shows the entire CSV (6 rows, 229 columns per row) for a preview. Now I just need to make each field editable and then insert the entire form upon submit. I  know how to insert a form to a database, so now I just need an idea of how to build the form within the while loop and create the names for each input, as well as how to fill the inputs with the actual CSV data.

Comment: Do you want individual row as a form ? or whole as a single form?

Comment: Whole csv as a form, technically. All 5 rows of the csv are unique. I was hoping the loop could create a 229 field form that repeated for the following 4 rows.

Comment: check these https://jsfiddle.net/pb8ok4rn/ you can make your form editable this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can create a form. Each form element is named like row1col1, row1col2, ro1col3 etc...

```
    $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $maxPreviewRows = PHP_INT_MAX;  // this will be ~2 billion on 32-bit system, or ~9 quintillion on 64-bit system
    $hasHeaderRow = true;
        echo '<form>\n';
        echo '<table>';

        /*WE WILL NEED TO QA CONDITIONS AND HIGHLIGHT IN RED HERE. ALSO NEED BORDER STYLINGS*/

        if ($hasHeaderRow) {
            $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
            echo '<thead><tr>';
            foreach($headerRow as $value) {
                echo "<th>$value</th>";
            }
            echo '</tr></thead>';
        }

        echo '<tbody>';

        $rowCount = 0;
        while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            $colCount = 0;
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach($row as $value) {
                echo "<td><input name='row".$rowCount."col".$colCount."' type='text' value='$value' /></td>";
                $colCount++;
            }
            echo '</tr>';

            if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
                break;
            }
        }
        echo '</tbody></table>';
        echo '<input type=\'submit\' value=\'Submit\' >';
        echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes the form perfectly. Two questions, though: (1) I tried a var_dump, but can't get it to print out the name of each input, is that ok? and (2) How would I then save those fields into my staging table? Would I just create an INSERT statement attached to the submit button and name each input in that statement row1col1 up to row5col229 ?

Comment: To get the names of each, upon form submission,  echo $_post in a foreach loop. That will give you all the names. Make sure that you have given method post in form tag.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you so much. So that gives me the names to build an explicit SQL insert statement with, but if there were ever more or less rows than this, is there a more general way that I can just loop and insert everything in this form to my staging table?

Comment: This should take care of any number of rows and columns. You will have to duplicate the same logic that generates rows and columns, even upon form submission. That would give you the names of all form elements.

Comment: You can even name elements like ele1, ele2, etc.. What ever suits your logic best..